# Remote Installation/Deployment of MSI/EXE files:

Tags: c#, xml, deployment, installation

Remote Installation/Deployment of MSI/EXE files:

I wanted to develop/explore the C# code for remote installation/deployment of MSI/EXE files. This remote installation of the applications should be done by taking the data from a XML file which has the remote computers IP addresses, port numbers, etc.

There are so many tools available presently for the remote installation/deployment, but i would like to develop the code or else explore the available code for remote installation/deployment.

Can anybody help me in this issue.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This really is quite a broad question covering a number of quite technical areas. I suggest you break it down and ask more targeted questions.

Comment: Remote Installation/Deployment of MSI/EXE files using XML data (IP addresses, port numbers..)

Answer (score 1):

Writing custom code for network deployment is not feasible. This type of deployment is so complex that your would need to create an entire framework around it.

So you have two options:

1. Use the built-in Microsoft tools: [Group Policy](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/816102) or [SCCM](http://www.microsoft.com/systemcenter/en/us/configuration-manager/cm-software-distribution.aspx)
2. Use a commercial network deployment tool

Each approach has it's own advantages and disadvantages, so you should research both of them before deciding.

Answer (score 0):

Although not fully what you are looking for, take a look at my post "Remote Unattended MSI Installation with PsExec" (http://www.geekytidbits.com/unattended-msi-installation-psexec/) which shows how to silently copy and install an MSI on a remote machine.  You would need to build a tool around this method to be able to read from your XML file and execute on multiple machines.

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, we would like you to include the essential parts of the linked article in your answer, and provide the [link for reference](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259). Failing to do that leaves the answer at risk from link rot.